# Rendering incremental updates with *ngFor?

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, rxjs

If we have an `Observable<Todo[]>`, as shown below, is it possible to provide the template with delta updates?  For example if the `Observable<Todo[]>` is getting values from a `BehaviorSubject`'s `next()` call, could that broadcast incremental changes.  My current understanding is that it has to broadcast the entire new array, but figured I'd check see if anything in this space is available?

```
 template: '<todo *ngFor="let todo of todos$ | async" [todo]="todo"><todo>'
```

### Background

I'm attempting to design an `Entity` store that is reactive and clients can subscribe to streaming feeds of the store.  So for example we could do:

```
const todoStore = new Store<Todo>();
const all:Observable<Todo[]> = todoStore.selectAll();
```

or

```
const add:Observable<Todo[]> = todoStore.selectAdd();
```

So if we can do incremental updates with the template rendering then the `BehaviorSubject<Todo>` only needs to broadcast the next `Todo` instance that was just added, allowing greater efficiency.

All of the instances are tracked by assigning a `UUID` that is keyed by a symbol `const ID = Symbol('GUID')`.  `todo[ID] = uuid()`.

Comment: Yes you can by using `trackBy`, but what kind of incremental changes do you want to happen?

Comment: @cgTag I added some background to the question.  I'm somewhat new to this space, so any other feedback on approach would be greatly appreciated.  Once I have things tested out more the project will be opened source here: https://github.com/fireflysemantics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When rendering lists, generally using `*ngFor`, you can use `trackBy`. It helps Angular understand and track which element was added or removed from the list with the help of a unique identifier for it.

Now, whenever the list changes, Angular will track which item(s) were added or removed and create or destroy only the items that changed.

Here's how you can implement it

In your Template:

```
<todo 
  *ngFor="let todo of todos$ | async;trackBy: trackByFunction" 
  [todo]="todo">
<todo>
```

In your TypeScript Class:

```
trackByFunction(index, item) {
  return item.uniqueIdentifier || index;
}
```

A better way would be to return an id or a unique identifier on the `item` if there is.

Comment: Perfect I'm tracking each entity using a symbol that keys a UUID for each instance, so this is going to work great!  Thank you very much for the heads up!

Comment: Glad I helped. Happy Jamming :)