# Broadcasting incremental changes only to *ngFor?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I thought I had the [solution per this question: rendering-incremental-updates-with-ngfor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52133889/rendering-incremental-updates-with-ngfor), but what I meant to ask was is it possible to send incremental changes only to`*ngFor`?

For example suppose the component has already rendered an array of 10 `Todo` instances.  Is it possible for the subject that broadcasts the instances to send a delta update only?

Can we do `subject.next(todo)` only broadcasting the `todo` just added for example?

Just looking at it it seems obvious that it can't because there's no way to know whether it's deleting or adding the item with that API call, but I'm hoping that perhaps there's something like:

```
subject.delete(todo)//delete the todo
subject.put(todo)//update todo
subject.post(todo)//add another todo
```

And these methods would pass along additional metadata that would allow incremental changes to be made?

Comment: You can wrap each emission with some object `{ type: ADD, item: {}}` and then use `scan` operator to add/remove/update its internal array.

Comment: Try to use track by: https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular use `differs` for that kind of situation. When you add `trackBy` to `*ngFor` angular use [IterableDiffer](https://angular.io/api/core/IterableDiffer) to track just [difference](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts#L160) between previous and current value.
  If you have complicated data structure it is possible to implement [custom](https://blog.mgechev.com/2017/11/14/angular-iterablediffer-keyvaluediffer-custom-differ-track-by-fn-performance/) `differ`.

Comment: Thanks - Great article on the custom differ.  I'm going to have to read up on that more.  I've created a simple to use store that offers delta updates that are keyed by update type, so I'm thinking that I can implement a custom differ to take advantage of the delta updates.

Comment: You are welcome. Do not forget to measure the performance improvement.
PS `premature optimization is the root of all evil` )